# What is the difference between macro expansion and parameter dereferencing in SOLR?

Tags: solr, solr8

I'm using Solr 8.11.

I've noticed in one of my ReRankQueries with LTR, that on an efi, it matters if I use:
**efi.some_name=${queryParam}** vs **efi.some_name=$queryParam**.

The single resource I found on the web was from a blog from 2014, calling the ${} notation, as the macro expansion one.

From what I experimented with, it seems that ${queryParam} is evaluated and the pasted there as is, for example, if queryParam="multi worded string", then efi.some_name=multi worded string, and this will require do be enclosed in ".

For the $queryParam, it seems that the query parser knows to associate the full value to efi.some_name.

What is the difference between those 2?

Comment: please share your findings here, when you understand how it works (or should work) :)